# COUNT Function Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I have the following table:

```
oDate                 oValue
-------------------------------
2019-01-01 00:00      90
2019-01-01 00:30      90
2019-01-01 01:00      86
2019-01-02 00:00      86
2019-01-02 00:30      90
2019-01-02 01:00      86
2019-01-02 01:30      90
```

I want to have the following result:

```
oDate          90     86
-----------------------------------
2019-01-01     2      1
2019-01-02     2      2
```

I want to have the count of each `oValue` for each different `oDate`.
Does anyone have the idea for this case?

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: `COUNTIFS()`...?

Comment: @HenryWoody, I tried, COUNTIFS, but confuse when selecting criteria.

Comment: for staters have you varified if your data under oDate is text or number?  This is very important in determining which formulas can be used.  Dates as strings/text in excel seem to cause a lot of grief.   You can test there with `=ISTEXT(A3)` where A3 is one of the cells with a date.  If it comes back as true you are dealing with text.

Comment: @ForwardEd, Source table is DateTime format. But the result is only Date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this under the *90* in the second table then drag right and down.

```
=COUNTIFS($A:$A, ">="&$D2, $A:$A, "<"&$D2+1, $B:$B, E$1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

COUNTIFS as given in another answer in my opinion is the way to go.  However if you are interested in seeing other potential methods, you could do this with SUMPRODUCT.  The reason I advise against it is as the data gets large, you can wind up doing an extrodinary number of calculations.  Also with SUMPRODUCT, since it is performing array calculations, full column references should be avoided.  Where as with COUNTIFS full column references wont make a difference.

So with SUMPRODUCT and assuming the layout in the picture below, use the following formula in C13 and copy down and to the right as required.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((INT($B$4:$B$10)=$B13)*($C$4:$C$10=C$12))
```

[image: POC]

Adjust the ranges to suit your data.

Comment: Hey, Thanks a lot. Is it possible to make `oValue` dynamic with SUMPRODUCT?

Comment: what do you mean by dynamic?  changing the length of the column as data is added?

Comment: Currently, oValue only 2 values (86&90), Then the result is static, I type the value manually. Is it possible to make it automatically? If the oValue is dynamic (not only 2 values)

Comment: you want to automatically generate a list of unique entries?  This can be done and its a separate question which has been asked before.  But to make it workable you would have to estimate a maximum potential number of variations and build out the table.  When the list of unique numbers has been exhausted, but the limits of the table have not, you will need to set it up for the headers to display "",  Subsequently your formulas in the body of the table  would need to be set up to display "" when header is "" else SUMPRODUCT.  I may have missed the boat here but that is my current understanding

Comment: and having said that I would still use COUNTIF and achieve the same thing

Comment: you want to automatically generate a list of unique entries? Yes, unique entries of `oValue`... So I don't need to type the unique value one by one.

Comment: Check the results of this google search: https://www.google.com/search?q=create+a+list+of+unique+values+in+excel&rlz=1C1CHBD_enCA757CA757&oq=create+a+list+of+unique+values&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j0l4.8383j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8